# Starting a ChatGPT chat with a reference to other chats

Tags: chatgpt

I would like to start a chat in ChatGPT in such a way that I am referencing other chats, that, I select, and include, prior to the chat. I also want to be able to do this in the middle of a chat.

Would this be at all possible in the ChatGPT web app?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this post is not a good fit for this site. Please check out the [tour] to learn the ropes of Web Applications Stack Exchange and [ask].

Comment: "I also want to be able to search chats by chat title or chat content." could be another question.